# Array manipulation and Typescript error in Vue JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, vue.js

I am trying to check if the items in one list (list A) are contained in another other list (list B), and if they are, a property/field of the corrisponding items in list B should change its boolean values.

Here is my code:

```
export default defineComponent({
  name: 'Users',
  props: {
      existingUsers : {
          type: Array as PropType<Array<UserModel>>,
      }
  },
  async setup(props) {
    const allUsers = ref<Array<UserModel>>(await userService.list())
    const userList = ref<Array<UserModel>>([{ id: 0, email: '', first_name: '', last_name: '', }])
   
    function defineUsers(): Array<UserModel> {
        if (props.existingUsers) {
            const existingUsers = props.existingUsers
            userList.value = allUsers.value
            .map((user: UserModel) => existingUsers
            .forEach((us: UserModel) => (us.id === user.id) ? user.isSelected = true : user)))
            return userList.value;
        } else {
            userList.value = allUsers.value
            return userList.value
        }
    }
    defineUsers();
```

Basically, if there are no existing users passed as props then the userList equals allUsers (which gets values from a GET request to an API). If there are existing users passed as props, then the variable allUsers shall be modified accordingly: each user in allUsers that is contained in existingUsers needs to set it 'isSelected' value to true.

This is the error I get related to userList.value on line 3 inside the function defineUsers:

> Type 'ComputedRef<void[]>' is missing the following properties from type '{ id: number; email: string; first_name: string; last_name: string; organization?: { id: number; company_name: string; address: string; postal_code: string; city: string; state: string; country: string; vat: string; fiscal_code?: string | undefined; codice_sdi?: string | undefined; registration_date?: string | undef...': length, pop, push, concat, and 28 more.Vetur(2740)

Any clue on how to solve this?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I solved it:

```
function defineUsers(): Array<UserModel> {
    if (props.existingUsers) {
        const existingUsers = props.existingUsers
        userList.value = allUsers.value.map((user: UserModel) => {
            let isSelected = existingUsers.some((us: UserModel) => 
                us.id === user.id
            );
            user.isSelected = isSelected;
            return user;
        });
        return userList.value;
    } else {
        return allUsers.value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can't use the .forEach method as return type, you need to do something like this

```
userList.value = allUsers.value.map((user: UserModel) =>
  existingUsers.map((us: UserModel) => {
    user.isSelected = us.id === user.id;
    return user;
  })
);
```

let me know if this work!

Comment: Grazie Cosimo. I now get the following error: Type 'UserModel[][]' is not assignable to type '{ id: number; email: string; first_name: ..... }'